# implementing interface across multiple versions

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to create a class that implements an interface from the Java library. ResultSet to be specific, though the particular interface shouldn't be relevant to the question. (I need to put a layer on top of a regular ResultSet that provides some additional functionality, but I'd like the "regular" functions to pass through, and I have a couple of functions that should be able to take either a regular ResultSet or my "enhanced" ResultSet.)

My problem is: Is there a way that I can do this so that the class will successfully compile in both Java 5 and Java 6?

There are a number of functions declared in the ResultSet interface in Java 6 that return objects not defined in Java 5. If I include these functions, my class won't compile in Java 5 because I'm referencing undefined types. But if I don't include these functions, then my class won't compile in Java 6 because I don't completely implement the interface. I seem to be stuck in something of a catch-22. I don't actually need any of these functions -- in fact my implementation just throws a "not implemented" exception for all of them.

Some of our programmers are running Java 5 and some are running Java 6. Our production environment is Java 5. I suppose in a more-perfect world we would all be running the same version. But even if I can modify our environment to make the problem moot in this case, surely this issue comes up with open source projects. And if I do modify my code to work with Java 5, then when, sooner or later, we upgrade to Java 6, the class will break, which seems pretty annoying.

**Update**

Well, thanks for the answers given. I was rather hoping that someone would tell me, "Oh, if you just add this annotation or type the letter 'W' here, it will all work magically." No such luck, I guess.

All the answers received (as of this update, anyway) make good points so I've upvoted all of them and I've given the "best answer" award to the one that best expresses my frustation. :-)

I think my real solution is going to be to abandon the idea of implementing ResultSet and instead create a new interface that includes just the functions from ResultSet that have to be implemented for the beast to work. I find this emotionally unsatisfying but, it appears, better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the Proxy suggestion is the best answer, but let me add two considerations:

First, to  change a public API by adding methods to an interface, methods which depend on classes that didn't exist in previous versions, is in general an abomination  (a developer that implements that interface, as yourself, is inevitably lead to trouble). This abomination is rare, and is attenuated by the second consideration:

The JDBC API is, of course, a public API. But not very public. I mean that normally its interfaces are to be implemented only by JDBC drivers providers. And in this case it's tolerable the burden of having different implementations for different JDBC versions - [see for eg](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). What I'm aiming to is to discourage you to implement a class that implements/wraps a ResultSet , except for very specific (low level) situations.In general it's bad practice to pass a ResultSet to bussiness layers; in the typical case, the JDBC driver instantiates the ResultSet, the DAO method uses it, but never return it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you should do is implement the service as a JDK proxy using the [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class.

It's been around since 1.3, so it will work in all versions.

The syntax is:

```
ResultSet rs = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                   ResultSet.class.getClassloader(),
                   new Class[]{ResultSet.class},
                   new ResultSetInvocationHandler()
);
```

And `ResultSetInvocationHandler` would be an implementation of [InvocationHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) that intercepts some methods with custom logic and passes others through.

Here is an ancient [tutorial about the proxy mechanism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html).

Comment: This will destroy static type safety, and involve writing a mass of boilerplate. It would be error-prone and inefficient. But it would definitely work!

Comment: @Tom Anderson *This will destroy static type safety* I know and that's what I don't like about it either. But everything that has compile time safety would require using CGLIB et al

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes, the great JDBC backwards compatibility debacle. You are entitled to release two pints of solid swearing in the direction of Sun for this one.

I don't think you have any way of using exactly the same implementation classes for 5 and 6. Could you, however, do something like:

```
abstract class JaysBaseSuperResultSet /* does not implement ResultSet */ {
    // all needed methods for java 5
}

class JaysSuperResultSetForJava6 extends JaysBaseSuperResultSet implements ResultSet {
    // all additional java 6 methods
}

class JaysSuperResultSetForJava5 extends JaysBaseSuperResultSetForJava5 implements ResultSet {
    // class body can be empty; compile this only with java 5
}
```

You will need to have a slightly weird build process: i think the simplest thing is to compile all but JaysSuperResultSetForJava5 with the 6 compiler, but with `-target 5`, then to compile that class alone with a 5 compiler, or with the 6 compiler but wired to the 5 libraries (which can be done and might be simpler).

You will then need a factory class which detects the current version and creates an instance of the appropriate concrete class.

You can then package everything up in a single JAR.

Does that sound like it would work?

EDIT: realised you can do this with three classes, not four.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a class that implements `ResultSet`, wrap a `ResultSet` in a new class.

One caveat:  Consider using generics to make it return the correct subinterface of `ResultSet`:

```
public class MyWrapper<T extends ResultSet> {
    T myResultSet;

    public MyWrapper(T myResultSet) {
        this.myResultSet = myResultSet;
    }

    public T getResultSet() {
        return myResultSet;
    }

    public void setResultSet(T myResultSet) {
        this.myResultSet = myResultSet;
    }

}
```

(Note, I haven't tested this).

Note:
Creating a new class that *implements* `ResultSet` may sound like a good idea on the surface, but quickly degenerates into madness due to `ResultSet` already having its own subinterface `RowSet`, which in turn has its own subinterface `JdbcRowSet`, which in turn has its own subinterfaces... and at the very end of this tree are the actual objects that are part of the JDBC driver for your database.

Comment: The catch here is that we have library A that includes a function that takes a ResultSet as a parameter. I am working on project B, which use library A. I could, in principle, overload the function in library A to take an instance of my new class in project B. But then I build a dependency on B into A, which seems like a bad idea. If all else fails, maybe I'll define an interface in library A that is a small subset of ResultSet, just the functions we actually use. But then I'd have to duplicate all the code in the version that takes ResultSet in another function taking a different type.

Comment: I don't really care what's "below" a ResultSet. I'm not writing my own JDBC interface. I'm just writing a class that provides some additional functions we need, some error handling, etc, while still wanting to give the caller access to basic next and getter methods. So I'm not adding a layer below, I'm adding a layer above. Anything underneath that I shouldn't have to know or care.

Comment: @jay that really sounds like you should be using Spring JDBC. I think you are re-inventing the wheel.